# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un .map?

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, map

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente, tengo el siguiente código:

```
 const overflow = timelineitems && timelineitems[0][Object.keys(datos)[80]].total_cases;
```

En el número 80 es la posición de una fecha:

```
Object.keys(datos)[80]
```

Si cambio el número 80 todo ok, se cambia la fecha.

Ahora bien, mi problema es que quiero intentar hacer un .map de todo los (total_cases) que tengo en el array: [link de la api que estoy usando](https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTimeline=US) estoy usando **timelineitems**

He intentado hacer varios .map sin éxito, mi último intento fue:

```
const datos = timelineitems && timelineitems[0];

const fechas = datos.map(item => Object.keys(item)[0].total_cases)
```

En mi intento de correr fecha me salio como error  // Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tu json no es un arreglo de jsons, es decir que tienes un json gigante que tiene multiples propiedades de fecha y no un objeto para cada fecha, es decir, no es iterable con `map` ya que map hace parte de los arreglos y no de los objetos, para solucionar esto no podras usar map, debido a que tu respuesta es un unico objeto pero con diferentes propiedades de fechas, sin embargo puedes usar un ciclo `for in` el cuál si permite recorrer un `objeto` sin problemas:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

    fetch("https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTimeline=US").then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(data =>{

        const total_cases = [];

        for(let date in data.timelineitems[0]){
            total_cases.push(data.timelineitems[0][date].total_cases);
        }

        console.log(total_cases);
    });

}
```

Como ves, te muestra todos los total_cases que hay en tu json, pero lo recomendable sería que la api no te diera esos datos así, lo recomendable sería que por cada fecha tengas un objeto diferente, para poder así usar map... pero bueno, ya que la api trae los datos así, tambien puedes usar esta manera.

Comment: mmm, he quedado igual pero igual manera gracia, lo que tenia mientra alguien me respondia era esto const datos = timelineitems && timelineitems[0];   datos.map(item => Object.keys(item)[0]), pero mi problema es coger todos los total_case de https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTimeline=US para luego colocarla en la data de mi charts,  :( tengo toda la noche, y siento que es algo basico

Comment: El map te debería estar cogiendo solo los total_cases de todos tus datos, saludos!.

Comment: no, solo me coge un solo dato item[Object.keys(item)[0]].total_cases, el caso numero 0 pero no sigue el bucle

Comment: Si, perdona, es que no vi bien la pregunta y pues al hacer un testeo me paso lo mismo que dices, sin embargo acabo de solucionarlo, checa de nuevo mi respuesta porfavor la edite.